# Partition an Array with duplicate elements into arrays with unique elements

Tags: java, arrays, unique, duplicates

I have an Array which is structured like this :

```
String Array = {"1","2","3","41","56","41","72","72","72","78","99"}
```

and I want to partition this array into a number of arrays which values are not duplicates... like this :

```
String Array1 = {"1","2","3","41","56","72","78","99"}
String Array2 = {"41","72"}
String Array3 = {"72"}
```

is there any straight way to do this in Java or I have to do this with ugly loops (Just kidding !) ?

Thanks !

> UPDATE

I'm gonna make the question a bit harder... now I have a Map which structure is like below :

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap(){{
    put("1@@96","10");
    put("2@@100","5");
    put("3@@23","100");
    put("41@@34","14");
    put("56@@22","25");
    put("41@@12","100");
    put("72@@10","100");
    put("72@@100","120");
    put("72@@21","0");
    put("78@@22","7");
}}
```

note that the values are not important BUT the keys are important...
what can I do to partition this map to submaps which are like :

```
Map map1 = {"1@@96" => "10"
            "2@@100" => "5"
            "3@@23" => "100"
            "41@@34" => "14"
            "56@@22" => "25"
            "72@@10" => "100"
            "78@@22" => "7"
            }

Map map2 = {
            "41@@12" => "100"
            "72@@100" => "120"
            }

Map map3 = {
            "72@@100" => "120"
            }
```

like before the first part of the map (before '@@') is the ID which I want the uniqueness be based upon... this is just like the Array Example but a bit harder and more complex...

Sorry for changing the question midway...

Comment: what do you mean ugly loops? you can just iterate over the original list and put the number into an appropriate resulting list by keeping track of which occurrence of a given number it is and N pointers, one per each resulting list, to know where to put the next number in each list. This requires the initial array to be sorted, though.

Comment: I was looking for a method in JDK or another library... But if it comes to worst, I surely will look into your advice... Thanks...

Comment: why Array1 has 8 items, Array2 has 2 itmes, and Array3 has 1? Is there any logic behind that?

Comment: Items in `Array1` appear only once in `Array`, items in `Array2` appear twice, etc.

Comment: there's completely no difference between the updated version and the original one, you still can use the solutions presented in the answers below since you can treat a map as an array of <key, val> entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably nothing in libs (seems not generic enough) but some ideas:

O(n) time and O(n) space complexity. Here you just count how many times each number occurs and then put them in that many resulting arrays.

@Edit: as @mpkorstanje pointed out if you change the input from numbers to strings or any other objects in the worst-worst case this will degrade to O(n^2). But in that case you should revise your hashing imho for the data on which you're working as it's not well distributed.

```
   public List<List<Integer>> split(int[] input) {
      Map<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
      int maxOcc = 0;
      for (int val : input) {
         int occ = 0;
         if (occurrences.containsKey(val)) {
            occ = occurrences.get(val);
         }
         if (occ + 1 > maxOcc) {
            maxOcc = occ + 1;
         }
         occurrences.put(val, occ + 1);
      }
      List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(maxOcc);
      for (int i = 0; i < maxOcc; i++) {
         result.add(new LinkedList<>());
      }
      for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occurrences.entrySet()) {
         for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
            result.get(i).add(entry.getKey());
         }
      }
      return result;
   }
```

O(nlogn) time and O(1) space complexity (not counting the resulting arrays) but doesn't retain order and "destroys" the input array. Here you utilize the fact that the array is already sorted so you can just go over it and keep adding the element to an appropriate resulting list depending on whether you're looking at a duplicate or a "new" entry.

```
   public List<List<Integer>> split(int[] input) {
      Arrays.sort(input);
      int maxDup = getMaxDuplicateNumber(input);
      List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(maxDup);
      for(int i = 0; i < maxDup; i++) {
         result.add(new LinkedList<>());
      }
      int count = 0;
      result.get(0).add(input[0]);
      for(int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
         if(input[i] == input[i-1]) {
            count++;
         } else {
            count = 0;
         }
         result.get(count).add(input[i]);
      }
      return result;
   }

   private int getMaxDuplicateNumber(int[] input) {
      int maxDups = 1;
      int currentDupCount = 1;
      for(int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
         if(input[i] == input[i - 1]) {
            currentDupCount++;
         } else {
            currentDupCount = 1;
         }
         if(currentDupCount > maxDups) {
            maxDups = currentDupCount;
         }
      }
      return maxDups;
   }
```

Comment: Nice! And for the heck of it, do you think this can be done in O(1) space with all the bins placed after each other. e.g. 

such that the output is an array with n sequences of strictly increasing values where n the max number of bins?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without loops. But you can use a set to remove some loops. You can add data structure trappings to your own liking.

I'm assuming here that the order of elements in the bins must be consistent with the order of the elements in the input array. If not this can be done more efficiently.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = { "1", "2", "3", "41", "56", "41", "72", "72", "72",
            "78", "99" };

    List<Set<String>> bins = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String s : array) {
        findOrCreateBin(bins, s).add(s);
    }

    System.out.println(bins); // Prints [[1, 2, 3, 41, 56, 72, 78, 99], [41, 72], [72]]

}

private static Set<String> findOrCreateBin(List<Set<String>> bins, String s) {
    for (Set<String> bin : bins) {
        if (!bin.contains(s)) {
            return bin;
        }
    }

    Set<String> bin = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    bins.add(bin);
    return bin;
}
```

Comment: were you able to get expected output?

Comment: in the worst case this will be O(n^2) if the initial array has all entries equal (i.e. {3,3,3,3,3,3,3}). You can go down to O(nlogn) time and O(1) space (well not counting the resulting sets/arrays) with sorting.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk could add in a look up that does the occurrence counting but I get the impression this is someone's homeowork assignment.

Comment: well you can do it in O(n) time with O(n) space and occurrence counting too, I guess

Comment: Strictly speaking not. You can pick a set of different strings such that their hash value is all equal in which case we're back at O(n^2). Your idea is better if the order in the bins is not important, otherwise you can't sort. Added more notes.

Comment: for strings and objects true, if we get as input numbers then it's doable though